# Mysql Query to get sum for each table where table name is stored in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which stores names of reports and for each entry I have a table where I have marks for each subject.

`Reports`

```
+------------+----------+
|    S.No.   |ReportName|
+------------+----------+
| 1          | Report1  |
| 2          | Report2  |
+------------+----------+
```

`Report1`

```
+------------+----------+
|    Subject | Marks    |
+------------+----------+
| Maths      | 78       |
| English    | 99       |
+------------+----------+
```

`Report2`

```
+------------+----------+
|    Subject | Marks    |
+------------+----------+
| Maths      | 80       |
| English    | 99       |
+------------+----------+
```

Now, I want to get sum of marks from each report as a table. I can do it for one table but not for all.

For one table it is:

```
SELECT (SUM(marks)) AS Total FROM `Report1`
```

Expected:

```
+------------+----------+
| ReportName | Marks    |
+------------+----------+
| Report1    | 177      |
| Report2    | 179      |
+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Add some more rows of sample data and also the expected result. What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Added my attempt and expected result. Can you please help now?

Comment: Poor db design. You should have one common report table, for all reports. Then you simply do a JOIN and GROUP BY. (Since you have one table per report you currently have to UNION ALL those report tables before you JOIN and GROUP BY. Just like D-shih now answered.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it

Use `UNION` to combine `Report1` and `Report2`

```
SELECT 'Report1' AS ReportName, SUM(Marks) AS Marks
FROM Report1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Report2' AS ReportName, SUM(Marks) AS Marks
FROM Report2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dd9c3c/1)

**EDIT**

Table's data format of `Rport1` and `Rport2` is the same.

I suggest you can combine table `Report1` and `Report2` be `InfoReport`

`InfoReport` can `join` with `Reports` by `ReportID`

```
+------------+----------+----------+
|    Subject | Marks    | ReportID |
+------------+----------+----------+
| Maths      | 78       |     1    |
| English    | 99       |     1    |
| Maths      | 80       |     2    |
| English    | 99       |     2    |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

New Query like this.

```
SELECT t1.ReportName as 'ReportName',
       SUM(T.Marks) as Marks
FROM InfoReport AS T
INNER JOIN Reports as T1 ON T.ReportID = T1.SNO
GROUP BY t1.ReportName
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9243db/3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to expicitly use name `Report1`, rather, I want to use `Reports` table for that.

Comment: The first select and the join isn't really useful, [you can remove it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c32959/9).

Comment: @naqushab Are there specifically related between Reports and other two tables ?

Comment: @naqushab, is there any link or constraint between the table Reports and the other tables? A foreign key? It seems that the relationships between the tables aren't really well designed.

Comment: @senape You are rigth. the `join` isn't useful. thank

Comment: @senape No.There is no relation other than the names of tables are same as the report table name.I am not very good at SQL.

Comment: Thanks! It really helped.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

[Aggregating functions in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) must be used in conjunction with group by.

In your case, you need to add it to

```
SELECT (SUM(marks)) AS Total FROM `Report1`
GROUP BY whatever_column
```

Furthermore, in your example, you probably want to join the "marks" column of the other reports, so you should consider using JOIN or UNION queries.

Comment: Not true. Consider `select count(*) from table`.

Comment: Of course there are exceptions, and count(*) is a good example, but I don't think that in this specific case the result can be obtained without grouping